# need to set GITHUB_TOKEN in Brownie but don't know how

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie

'm using VPN to connect to the internet (because the internet is partially restricted in my country)

when I run :

> brownie compile

```
 ConnectionError: Status 404 when getting package versions from Github: 'Not Found'

Missing or forbidden.
If this issue persists, generate a Github API token and store it as the environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN`:
https://github.blog/2013-05-16-personal-api-tokens/
```

I think it caused by Github rejecting my connection

I've tried to set github_token in dotenv like this:

export GITHUB_TOKEN = 'ghp_00000000000000000000000000000000000000'

also echo $GITHUB_TOKEN
[is blank]

in the brownie docs: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/ page 33 installing from GitHub said :

It is possible to install from a private Github repository using an API access token like a personal access token. This can be provided to Brownie via the GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable in the form of username:ghp_token_secret. See also https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/

also tried

export GITHUB_TOKEN='username:ghp_0000000000000000000000000000000000000'
in dotenv and no luck
but if try in terminal

export GITHUB_TOKEN='username:ghp_0000000000000000000000000000000000000'
now echo $GITHUB_TOKEN return the value but still no luck

```
 ConnectionError: Status 404 when getting package versions from Github: 'Not Found'

Missing or forbidden.
If this issue persists, generate a Github API token and store it as the environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN`:
https://github.blog/2013-05-16-personal-api-tokens/
```

but I don't know what to do in .env or brownie-config.yaml or how to setup GITHUB_TOKEN

thank you in advance

Comment: You just have to do: `pip install eth-brownie`

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies name and version in brownie-config.yaml. I got the same error, and correcting the dependencies worked for me.
Referred to the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295312/brownie-errors-when-attempting-to-compile